# How to change this find control for drop down to text box?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to select a value from a drop down control before it was text box. I have given the same ID for drop down which was similar to the text box.

Below is the code:

```
  Do
      counter=counter+1
        tempPanelInputBox = form1.FindControl("txt_" + panelUsed + "_input" + counter.ToString())
    Loop untill counter=CounterEnd
```

and i want to change to get the selected value in the dropdown box.

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure it's a Dropdownlist, just do a cast:

```
DropDownList tempPanelInputBox = (DropDownList)form1.FindControl("txt_" + panelUsed + "_input" + counter.ToString());

int selValue = tempPanelInputBox.SelectedValue; //or whatever you want to do with the  selected value
```

EDIT: In VB:

```
Dim tempPanelInputBox As DropDownList
tempPanelInput = CType(form1.FindControl("txt_" + panelUsed + "_input" + counter.ToString()), DropDownList)
```

Then access tempPanelInput.SelectedValue and do with it whatever you want.

Comment: When i paste ur code its givng error 

"Dropdown list is a type that cannot be used as an expression"

Comment: Can you tag this as VB.NET please?  Thanks.